# Is it possible that an Administrator do not have read/write access to a certain drive?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

I am in the process of writing some scripts to check a newly create windows server machine for certain conditions, like if user have admin rights, a particular drive exists, user have read/write access to that drive etc.

I was struggling a bit with checking of read/write permissions when I started thinking - Is it possible for an Admin to **not** have permissions on a certain drive?

I tested this by trying to create folders in user directories of other admins and i was able to do so. If it is impossible not to have write access as admin, i will drop this check. But if it is possible, **then how can i check if i do not have the write permissions ?**

Comment: `Is it possible for an Admin to not have permissions on a certain drive?` - Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

I have created the user "Test" and added it to the local administrators group:
[image]

I have created a folder "ServerFault" on my desktop and removed "Administrators" permissions:
[image]

I start a shell as my "Test" user, and try to access this directory:

[image]

So even though the user is an Administrator, the individual folder permissions block the access.

How to check programmatically if you have write permissions largely depends on what language you are writing in, and would rather be a question for StackOverflow.

**Edit 1:**.. but hey, I can give you pointers.
In C++ for example, you could use the [OpenFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365430(v=vs.85).aspx) function to open a file for writing.

If the function fails, you can call GetLastError(), if this error value is 5, you have no write access as the user that's running your program.

**Edit 2:** Since you're using Powershell, you could use the CACLS command and parse the outputs.

```
PS C:\Users\csa> cacls C:\temp | findstr "Administrator"
C:\Temp BUILTIN\Administrators:(ID)F
        BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(IO)(ID)F
```

From the "help":

```
 Perm can be: R  Read
              W  Write
              C  Change (write)
              F  Full control
```

and

```
 Abbreviations:
    CI - Container Inherit.
         The ACE will be inherited by directories.
    OI - Object Inherit.
         The ACE will be inherited by files.
    IO - Inherit Only.
         The ACE does not apply to the current file/directory.
    ID - Inherited.
         The ACE was inherited from the parent directory's ACL.
```

So in this case, the users from the builtin Administrators group have Full control because they Inherited it from the permissions set on the C:\ directory.

Comment: Thanks. This proves i was wrong to assume that. I am looking for some command in CMD or powershell to check if current user have write access or not. If you have some nice way of doing that (no .bat or .ps1) then it would be great.

Comment: I've updated my answer :-) You still have to parse the outputs tho, I suck at powershell!